# C - Store global variables in flash?

Tags: c, embedded

As the title may suggest, I'm currently short on SRAM in my program and I can't find a way to reduce my global variables. Is it possible to bring global variables over to flash memory? Since these variables are frequently read and written, would it be bad for the `nand flash` because they have limited number of read/write cycle?

If the flash cannot handle this, would `EEPROM` be a good alternative?

EDIT:
Sorry for the ambiguity guys. I'm working with Atmel AVR ATmega32HVB which has:
  2K bytes of SRAM, 
  1K bytes of EEPROM 
  32K bytes of FLASH

Compiler: AVR C/C++

Platform: IAR Embedded AVR

The global variables that I want to get rid of are:

```
uint32_t capacityInCCAccumulated[TOTAL_CELL];
```

and

```
int32_t AccumulatedCCADCvalue[TOTAL_CELL];
```

Code snippets:

```
  int32_t AccumulatedCCADCvalue[TOTAL_CELL];
    void CCGASG_AccumulateCCADCMeasurements(int32_t ccadcMeasurement, uint16_t slowRCperiod)
{ 
    uint8_t cellIndex;
    // Sampling period dependant on configuration of CCADC sampling..
    int32_t temp = ccadcMeasurement * (int32_t)slowRCperiod;

    bool polChange = false;
    if(temp < 0) {
        temp = -temp;
        polChange = true;
    }

    // Add 0.5*divisor to get proper rounding
    temp += (1<<(CCGASG_ACC_SCALING-1));
    temp >>= CCGASG_ACC_SCALING;

    if(polChange) {
        temp = -temp;
    }
    for (cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < TOTAL_CELL; cellIndex++)
    {
        AccumulatedCCADCvalue[cellIndex] += temp;
    }

    // If it was a charge, update the charge cycle counter
    if(ccadcMeasurement <= 0) {
        // If it was a discharge, AccumulatedCADCvalue can be negative, and that
        // is "impossible", so set it to zero
        for (cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < TOTAL_CELL; cellIndex++)
        {
            if(AccumulatedCCADCvalue[cellIndex] < 0) 
            {
                AccumulatedCCADCvalue[cellIndex] = 0;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

And this

```
uint32_t capacityInCCAccumulated[TOTAL_CELL];
void BATTPARAM_InitSramParameters() {
        uint8_t cellIndex;
        // Active current threshold in ticks
    battParams_sram.activeCurrentThresholdInTicks = (uint16_t) BATTCUR_mA2Ticks(battParams.activeCurrentThreshold);

        for (cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < TOTAL_CELL; cellIndex++) 
        {
    // Full charge capacity in CC accumulated
            battParams_sram.capacityInCCAccumulated[cellIndex] = (uint32_t) CCGASG_mAh2Acc(battParams.fullChargeCapacity);
    }
    // Terminate discharge limit in CC accumulated
    battParams_sram.terminateDischargeLimit = CCGASG_mAh2Acc(battParams.terminateDischargeLimit);

    // Values for remaining capacity calibration
    GASG_CalculateRemainingCapacityValues();
}
```

Comment: Writing flash memory and EEPROM are generally slow and it may not be good for frequently-changing values. By the way, are you talking about microcomputer? If so, please specify what microcomputer your target is.

Comment: What is your platform? Which compiler?

Comment: EEPROM also has limited number of writes. Wouldn't recomend that. Maybe show us some code we will try to help you reducing them.

Comment: Putting actual *variables* in FLASH is a bad idea, if you have lots of constant or read-only data on the other hand, then that would fit very well there, and the same with the actual code.

Comment: Read only from flash does not reduce the life time of flash. Erasing and writing will reduce the flash lifetime.

Comment: But HacLe said that these variables are often read and written to, that's why it's not a good idea to use it.

Comment: @DawidPi: Nowadays EEPROM is most times also Flash.

Comment: The flash of the microcontroller is NOR flash not NAND flash. NOR flash is memory mapped and code can be executed from it directly.

Comment: Hasnt this question been asked and answered before?  ran out of ram can I use flash/rom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any kind of Flash is a bad idea to be used for frequently changing values:

- limited number of erase/write cycles, see datasheet.
- very slow erase/write (erase can be ~1s), see datasheet.
- You need a special sequence to erase then write (no language support).
- While erasing or writing accesses to Flash are blocked at best, some require not to access the Flash at all (undefined behaviour).
- Flash cells cannot freely be written per-byte/word. Most have to be written per page (e.g. 64 bytes) and erased most times in much larger units (segments/blocks/sectors).

For NAND Flash, endurance is even more reduced compared to NOR Flash and the cells are less reliable (bits might flip occasionally or are defective), so you have to add error detection and correction. This is very likely a direction you should not go.

True EEPROM shares most issues, but they might be written byte/word-wise (internal erase).

Note that modern MCU-integrated "EEPROM" is most times also Flash. Some implementations just use slightly more reliable cells (about one decade more erase/write cycles than the program flash) and additional hardware allowing arbitrary byte/word write (automatic erase). But that is still not sufficient for frequent changes.

However, you first should verify if your application can tolerate the lengthly write/erase times. Can you accept a process blocking that long, or rewrite your program acordingly? If the answer is "no", you should even stop further investigation into that direction. Otherwise you should calculate  the number of updates over the expected lifetime and compare to the information in the datasheet. There are also methods to reduce the number of erase cycles, but the leads too far.

If an external device (I2C/SPI) is an option, you could use a serial SRAM. Although the better (and likely cheaper) approach would be a larger MCU or think about a more efficient (i.e. less RAM, more code) way to store the data in SRAM.

Comment: Thanks for the tips Olaf. I think I wouldn't be able to replace the MCU any time soon. Trimming global variables is also an option in this case. I have several global arrays that are referenced between functions in the code. Is there any way to reduce SRAM consumption of these arrays?

Comment: @HacLe: Without analysing your whole code, this is not possible. It is a very complex task and might result in major changes, Note that it is off-topic on SO (in case you think about making it a question). Personal advise: double-check your requirements and be creative.

Comment: @HacLe: First thing to check is if you really need 32 bit integers. They are also quite costly to process ona 8 bit MCU like the AVR.

Answer (score 3):

> would it be bad for the nand flash because they have limited number of
>   read/write cycle?

Yes it's not a good idea to use flash for frequent modification of data.
Read only from flash does not reduce the life time of flash. Erasing and writing will reduce the flash lifetime.

Reading and writing from flash is substantially slower compared to conventional memory.

To write a byte whole block has to be erased and re written in flash.

Comment: Thanks Kumar, it seems Flash and EEPROM are off the table :).